# Bootstrap input-append overflows in small containers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

It appears that it's awkward if you need a fluid-width text field with an `add-on` in Bootstrap 2.3.2.

If the containing `div` becomes smaller than the input field, an `input` with a `span12` class on it will resize quite happily.

However, doing the same to this snippet is a bit more difficult

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input type="text">
    <span class="add-on">Sheep</span>
</div>
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KFr2z/149/

Answer (score 1):

If you have input alone it is very easy to expand it to fit parent. It is also easy for more than one element if other has % width. Problem become if you have more than one element and other elements has fixed width or no explicitly determined width at all. Then you need an element which fit all parent's remaining space. From what I know it is impossible to make input to behave that way. But any native block-level element enclosing input should do the trick:

```
  <div class="input-append">
    <span class="add-on" style="float: right;">Sheep</span>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
      <input type="text" class="span12">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Bootstrap use some styles based on childs' order so you should also set`border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0` because it doesn't apply to add-on any more.

Comment: The text field also needs to have a width of 100%. Here's a fiddle of this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/KFr2z/155/

Comment: "span12" class, which you also mentioned in your question, applied to input ensure 100% width. But of course span12 is useless until you use row-fluid class somewhere in parents hierarchy.